# Cómo obtener datos tiene un array con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con una funcion ya que quiero obtener unos datos de este array pero no mas bien no me acurdo de como hacer eso lo que quiero es sacar la informacion del `URL` y `FORMAT` si me pueden dar una mano :)

```
array(5) {
  [22]=>
  array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(670) "https://r3---sn-vgqs7ney.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=1142500&nh=IgpwZjAxLm9yZDM1Kg42Ni4yMDguMjI4LjIwMQ&key=yt6&mime=video%2Fmp4&mn=sn-vgqs7ney&mm=31&id=o-APybfQxBq_Uf0UwtAWdBuT2hoXzus5lvuXnd9VSmh5Dl&ip=67.184.200.25&gcr=us&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mt=1482861742&ms=au&pl=16&itag=22&ei=Fq1iWM-PIsLyugLMor-gBA&mv=m&source=youtube&upn=pDkyvSW9InM&dur=265.357&ipbits=0&expire=1482883446&lmt=1478829845344913&signature=A27686411B20AD4EB61A29BC695509DB4D003681.9AE606614F809319EEE0B230BFCEFD09F5C39E12"
    ["format"]=>
    string(13) "MP4 720p (HD)"
  }
  [43]=>
  array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(704) "https://r3---sn-vgqs7ney.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=1142500&nh=IgpwZjAxLm9yZDM1Kg42Ni4yMDguMjI4LjIwMQ&key=yt6&gir=yes&mime=video%2Fwebm&mn=sn-vgqs7ney&mm=31&id=o-APybfQxBq_Uf0UwtAWdBuT2hoXzus5lvuXnd9VSmh5Dl&clen=23934795&ip=67.184.200.25&gcr=us&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mt=1482861742&ms=au&pl=16&itag=43&ei=Fq1iWM-PIsLyugLMor-gBA&mv=m&source=youtube&upn=pDkyvSW9InM&dur=0.000&ipbits=0&expire=1482883446&lmt=1466552369088504&signature=4A9B43F989EF4DB937C56AC889BF9AFAA1363439.87B358B93A19E3C292BE823A2E7FD505E527956C"
    ["format"]=>
    string(9) "WebM 360p"
  }
  [18]=>
  array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(705) "https://r3---sn-vgqs7ney.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=1142500&nh=IgpwZjAxLm9yZDM1Kg42Ni4yMDguMjI4LjIwMQ&key=yt6&gir=yes&mime=video%2Fmp4&mn=sn-vgqs7ney&mm=31&id=o-APybfQxBq_Uf0UwtAWdBuT2hoXzus5lvuXnd9VSmh5Dl&clen=18431345&ip=67.184.200.25&gcr=us&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mt=1482861742&ms=au&pl=16&itag=18&ei=Fq1iWM-PIsLyugLMor-gBA&mv=m&source=youtube&upn=pDkyvSW9InM&dur=265.357&ipbits=0&expire=1482883446&lmt=1478827692757115&signature=0C2203FABCEBC01A0B154C109EA7A03EBB778A17.7FFE657A41B06ABB4729E03253A92E1AA5562D3E"
    ["format"]=>
    string(8) "MP4 360p"
  }
  [36]=>
  array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(677) "https://r3---sn-vgqs7ney.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=1142500&nh=IgpwZjAxLm9yZDM1Kg42Ni4yMDguMjI4LjIwMQ&key=yt6&gir=yes&mime=video%2F3gpp&mn=sn-vgqs7ney&mm=31&id=o-APybfQxBq_Uf0UwtAWdBuT2hoXzus5lvuXnd9VSmh5Dl&clen=7400500&ip=67.184.200.25&gcr=us&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mt=1482861742&ms=au&pl=16&itag=36&ei=Fq1iWM-PIsLyugLMor-gBA&mv=m&source=youtube&upn=pDkyvSW9InM&dur=265.404&ipbits=0&expire=1482883446&lmt=1466551971126275&signature=121F4D6F18C10D31951E2C2A857E52351BCC1A8C.B6EFCCB6734190053A0F3980FC67D3E508EA30FF"
    ["format"]=>
    string(7) "Unknown"
  }
  [17]=>
  array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(677) "https://r3---sn-vgqs7ney.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=1142500&nh=IgpwZjAxLm9yZDM1Kg42Ni4yMDguMjI4LjIwMQ&key=yt6&gir=yes&mime=video%2F3gpp&mn=sn-vgqs7ney&mm=31&id=o-APybfQxBq_Uf0UwtAWdBuT2hoXzus5lvuXnd9VSmh5Dl&clen=2661359&ip=67.184.200.25&gcr=us&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mt=1482861742&ms=au&pl=16&itag=17&ei=Fq1iWM-PIsLyugLMor-gBA&mv=m&source=youtube&upn=pDkyvSW9InM&dur=265.404&ipbits=0&expire=1482883446&lmt=1466551946325771&signature=9C0017C6EE3EC754BCB73E4546483807143CC495.A738E50D2B2C9073E9369A8828BA780B6BA453F7"
    ["format"]=>
    string(8) "3GP 144p"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes recorrer tu arreglo con un foreach y hacer referencia a los elementos que necesitas extraer, por ejemplo si tu arreglo se llamara $tuarray:

```
foreach($tuarray as $indice => $tuarra)
{
    echo "url ".$indice.": ". $tuarra['url'];
    echo "format ".$indice.": ". $tuarra['format'];

}
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\all\demo.php on line 399

Comment: porque me da error?

Comment: le pasaste como argumento el array que contiene tus datos? puedes colocar como lo hiciste?

Comment: se lo pase con esta funcion

Comment: `function var_dump_ret($mixed = null) {
 ob_start();
 var_dump($mixed);
 $content = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 return $content;
}`

Comment: le pasaste esa funcion tal cual? deberias guardar el resultado de esa función, (que por lo que entiendo es la que genera tu arreglo) en una variable y luego pasarsela al foreach, a el foreach debes enviarle el arreglo que va a recorrer no una funcion, algo asi como: $tuarray = var_dump_ret(); y luego le pasas $tuarray al foreach

Comment: si me funciono gracias :)